# Weird orange rust spots appearing in holes on freshly painted basement cinder blocks

Tags: concrete, basement, paint

I've started to paint my basement with white primer, and on one wall weird orange spots appeared in the holes I had "filled" with the primer.

The wall is made of dark cinder blocks which are pretty rough. I have to use a lot of primer in general with the roller and need to touch up with a paintbrush all the major holes to fill them.

At some point during painting I noticed the yellowing in one hole, but didn't think much of it and filled it again.

After 3-4 hours I checked on the wall again and saw 2 dozens such spots in a bright orange color, much like rust. One other wall isn't affected at all, but the primer I used was a different brand. Now I'm using a new KILZ 2. Before, I was finishing a Benjamin Moore white satin paint.

As you can see from the picture the hole is still "closed" by the paint.

[image: Weird orange spot on freshly painted cinder blocks]

In that section the wall is pretty dry. We've had some efflorescence near the ground (which I've removed), but not at all where I'm painting now. The wall is 25% above ground and the spots have appeared both above and underground.

The wall was also painted with just one layer 8 years ago on one section of the same wall before we bought the house, and I've now noticed the same spots.

Any idea what that could be? I'll be continuing with the painting over the next days.

Here's a picture of the unpainted cinder blocks. 
[image]

Comment: I'm thinking your concrete blocks have some bits of iron in them (not at all uncommon) that is being oxidized by the water and other chemicals in your primer.  Try a variety of sealer/primer that specifically lists "rust inhibitor" as an ingredient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The orange stain is likely an iron ochre infiltration due to high levels of iron in the soil or pre-existing iron in the cinder block. [More info](https://www.basementsystems.com/company/news-and-events/28616-5-ugly-stains-on-basement-walls-what-are-they-and-how-to-cope.html)

The paint is simply making the orange much more visible than it was on bare cinder block.

I highly advise reading [this article on basement finishing](https://www.1800gotmold.com/mold-facts/dont-finish-your-basement-until-you-read-this.php) before continuing to paint your basement. You will likely have to re-paint next year because moisture is merciless and you might even cause mold issues for yourself which weren't present before.

If you really want to make the cinder block look nicer then you can try staining it. [More info](https://www.hunker.com/12265395/how-to-stain-a-concrete-block-wall)

Below is a picture of my basement wall which was [Drylok'd](https://www.homedepot.com/p/DRYLOK-1-Gal-White-Masonry-Waterproofer-27513/100118662) about 4 years ago by the previous owner. Note: it looked like new when we moved in and it quickly went to crap.

[image: mold and rust on dry-locked basement wall]

Comment: Thank you. I under from this that the ochre color is indeed an infiltration, and that I shouldn't be painting the wall... that's going to disappoint the missus (and it does indeed look better painted...)
Is there a way to paint while retaining some porosity that would allow the blocks to "breathe" ?

Comment: @GCord Paint it or don't paint it; it's your house I won't lose any sleep over it. I just wanted you to understand the pros and cons of your choices.

Comment: @GCord Your Googling skills are probably on par with mine but I would imagine that raw cinder block looks better than the rust and eventual mold. If you're going to finish the basement then do so properly; until then every "solution" is just a stop-gap.

Comment: I don't think there is any sort of "porous painting method". A single block has thousands of pores and each one has the potential to allow water so if a blotch of paint is covering that pore then that blotch will blister and peel.

Comment: @GCord Now that I think about it you can try staining the cinder block. I updated my answer with a resource.

Comment: thanks. Do you have experience in sealing? I've been looking into it and most sites explain to also "seal" after staining. Moreover, the staining seems to be water-intensive, which isn't very practical in the basement. Do you have first-hand experience with staining, and how one should go about in the basement? 
Further question would be: how does one remove the paint off a basement wall, to replace with stain?
PS: why can't I refer to your name with the "at" sign? @MonkeyZeus ?

Comment: We're the only two people on this comment thread so we get notified even without the "@". I don't have experience with stains but my understanding is that it simply soaks into the cinder and stains it. I think you can skip the sealing part because you want your walls to breath. I would buy a cinder block from the store and test out how to properly stain it. As for the existing paint I would imagine you can scrape it off with a wire brush and maybe some acetone or wait for it to flake off. Stain what you can for now and finish the rest once the paint is gone.

Comment: Whatever you do just make sure to have good ventilation and maybe a respirator if you're sensitive.

Comment: @GCord I added a picture of my basement wall to give you an idea of what happens to a painted basement surface over time.

Comment: @GCord [Here](https://photos-us.bazaarvoice.com/photo/2/cGhvdG86aG9tZWRlcG90/02c895c6-06bd-5e4c-acc2-09688e4e8a6a) is a customer photo from the Home Depot reviews of Drylok which show the same thing happening as my basement.

Comment: Thanks @MonkeyZeus, very clear. Since my wall is already 70% painted, I'll try one thing: lightly scrape the "holes" where the yellow appeared. That may let the wall breathe through those holes. I'll try that and report back after a few months. I may also apply paint on the rest of the wall but without filling in any holes. Same thing, it should let the wall breathe. If it flakes I'll take the paint down.

Comment: @GCord The rust spots are not an indication of where the wall needs to breathe, it's an indication of where you have iron deposits. The entire cinder block needs to breathe. Anyways, good luck to you. I look forward to an update in 5 years to see if the wall turns out better than anticipated.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus What (if anything) did you do with your walls after your walls became like that?

Comment: @Kirkman14 Nothing yet. I just curse the previous owners for causing me the headache. Apparently bleach is harmful to Drylok and you need a respirator if you plan to scrape it off; that is in addition to making your walls accessible in the first place. Apparently dedicated mold killing sprays work better than bleach but I have no clue if they damage the Drylok.

Answer (score 1):

The stains are minor, but may get worse over time due to moisture seeping through the porous concrete block from the outside.

In order to have a dry basement, it is usually necessary to waterproof the foundation from the outside. This is generally not a DIY project since it involves digging all the way down to the footing in order to access the foundation walls. If the foundation is not waterproofed from the outside, water will continue to seep in. When the foundation walls are waterproofed from the outside, it is common practice to put in a gravel base and pipes around the footings that will capture the water and divert it away from the foundation. This is known as a French drain system.

If the inside walls are continuously wet, painting over them with sealer is not a good idea. The water will saturate the concrete and not be able to dry out. Over time, this can cause the foundation walls to break down and cause more serious issues.